# Is it possible to reuse docs generated by Doxygen and merge with new documentation?

Tags: documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

Since the codebase is quite large, Doxygen takes a really long time to run. If I could obtain the modified files from some version control system and run Doxygen on them, is it possible to merge the existing documentation with the new pages generated?

If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen does not have an incremental build, though there are some mechanisms that do speedup the generation slightly:

- Generated images (e.g. call  graphs, inheritance graphs are "cached" i.e. in short a md5sum is stored and when this does not change for the graph the image is not regenerated)
- for "independent" parts it is possible to create "tag" files (see documentation e.g. TAGFILES)